# Test Windows driver in Visual Studio (local)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver, wdk

I'm developing a Windows driver using Visual Studio + WDK, but i'm not able to test it.

There's a [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/testing-a-driver-at-runtime) about it, that says:

> A test computer (or computers). The test computer must be on the same
>   network as the computer that you are using for development.

But I don't have another computer.

Does anyone knows a way to test using the same computer that i'm using to develop (local debuggin)?

I'm using:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.5.2
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.5.2+27130.2010
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02558
Windows Driver Kit   10.0.16292.1001
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Virtual Machine, I do this frequently but sometimes I prefer to use a physical machine. The Virtual Machine method will use a named pipe for Inter-Process Communication (IPC) between Visual Studio (the WinDbg engine is used) and the Virtual Machine environment; you'll preferably want to use VMWare but I have not used VirtualBox for this before.

See the following article please:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/attaching-to-a-virtual-machine--kernel-mode-

You cannot however debug your kernel-mode software while it is active on your actual Host environment; testing kernel-mode software on your Host environment until you are certain it will go well is a bad idea anyway because data corruption is caused by BSOD crashes so if a BSOD crash occurs, you can lose sensitive and important data unexpectedly.